# Query for Objects with Pointer Array in Parse

Tags: objective-c, swift, parse-platform

- I have an array of `[PFObjects]` called `restaurantsArray`.
- Within Parse, there is a Class: `FoodPhotos` with pointers to RestaurantName (the objects in `restaurantsArray`)

How can I query for all objects within `FoodPhotos` that contain the pointer to an object in `restaurantsArray`.

#### Class "FoodPhotos":

[image]

Basically I want to grab all the Food Photos that contain a pointer to an object in `restaurantArray`

Comment: Minor suggestion: It helps to keep your class name singular like `FoodPhoto` instead of  `FoodPhotos`. An array called `foodPhotos` would contain many `FoodPhoto` objects.

Comment: You're right! I noticed the solution below wasn't working because my class is actually singular haha. Posted my swift version in the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test this code right now to be sure it works, but you could try something like the following:

```
PFQuery *query = [FoodPhotos query]; // Or ... = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FoodPhotos"];
[query whereKey:@"RestaurantName" containedIn:restaurantArray];
```

This should only return `FoodPhotos` objects who's `RestaurantName` column matches one of the objects in `restaurantArray`.

Comment: Thanks, swift is something like `var query = PFQuery(className:"FoodPhoto") query.whereKey("RestaurantName", containedIn: restaurantArray)`