# PFQuery where array of pointers contains a certain PFObject

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

Objects in my class `Deal` have an attribute `relatedContacts` which is an array of pointers to `Contact` objects. I'm running the following query to determine whether the current `Contact` object is the target of a pointer in any `Deal`, prior to deleting the `Contact`.

```
let relatedContactObjects:NSArray = [self.contactObject] as NSArray

let relatedContactQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Deal")
    relatedContactQuery.fromLocalDatastore()
    relatedContactQuery.fromPinWithName("Deals")
    relatedContactQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    relatedContactQuery.whereKey("relatedContacts", containsAllObjectsInArray: relatedContactObjects as [AnyObject])
```

However this returns Parse Error 102: "Value type not supported for $all queries."

The Parse [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:containsAllObjectsInArray:) says that `containsAllObjectsInArray` takes an NSArray, but Xcode shows a warning that `NSArray is not implicity convertible to [AnyObject]`.

Any ideas how I can make this query work?

**Edit:** I looked at the contents of `relatedContacts` and it seems that each instance contains an array of dictionaries, example: `[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Contact","objectId":"BoLym053hX"},{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Contact","objectId":"AgpnxAFUBn"},{"__type":"Pointer","className":"Contact","objectId":"ob20tThdfp"}]`

As suggested, I've also looked at the `containedIn` query constraint, but that is used to identify objects that are contained in a given array. I am trying to identify arrays that contain a given object.

Comment: At the top you have relatedContactObjects as an NSArray, why are you casting it to [AnyObject] ?

Comment: Xcode requires that it be cast to [AnyObject], but actually I don't think that is the problem. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Don't think that method supports that [kind of thing](http://blog.parse.com/learn/engineering/find-all-the-things/). You might want to try `containedIn`  [This question may help.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388407/query-for-objects-with-pointer-array-in-parse)

Comment: Thanks, but that constraint is used to identify objects that are contained in a given array. I am trying to identify arrays that contain a given object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parse.com overloads equalTo: by allowing it to mean either: (a) a singular property equals the operand, or (b) an array property contains the operand.  So you're objective is easily stated as follows:

```
relatedContactQuery.fromPinWithName("Deals")
relatedContactQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
relatedContactQuery.whereKey("relatedContacts", equalTo:self.contactObject)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I thought equalTo was more literal. And just to complete your answer, here is the countObjects query I used: `relatedContactQuery.countObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(count, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                self.dealsPointingToContactCount = Int(count)
                
            }`

Comment: Glad it helped.  Fyi: Parse.com disuades count queries.  Depending on the count, a resource saving alternative might be a cloud function that does a find() and then answers the length of the found collection.

Comment: Good to know. I'm running the query in the local datastore and the expected count is less than 100, so this should be okay for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the accepted answer, I also tried using loops to go through the arrays and identify whether they contained the current object, then incremented a count.

```
var dealsPointingToContactCount:Int = 0
func countDealsRelatedToContact() {
    let dealsWithRelatedContactQuery:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Deal")
    dealsWithRelatedContactQuery.fromLocalDatastore()
    dealsWithRelatedContactQuery.fromPinWithName("Deals")
    dealsWithRelatedContactQuery.whereKey("user", equalTo:PFUser.currentUser()!)
    dealsWithRelatedContactQuery.whereKeyExists("relatedContacts")
    dealsWithRelatedContactQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{(objects, error) -> Void in

        if (error == nil) {

            var dealsWithPointersToContacts:NSArray = objects! as NSArray

            for deal in dealsWithPointersToContacts {

                var dealContactsArray:NSArray = deal["relatedContacts"] as! [PFObject]

                for contact in dealContactsArray {
                    if contact as! PFObject == self.object {
                        self.dealsPointingToContactCount++
                        println("Deals pointing to current contact: \(self.dealsPointingToContactCount)")
                    }
                }
            }  
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can do it the way you were first attempting.  This way is okay, but consider that it will retrieve (using network resource and client memory) potentially many more objects than are needed.  There's also the matter of expending compute effort on the local test.  To get what you want via query, please clarify:  objects where EVERY related contacts is in `relatedContactObjects`. Also, please indicate the type of the relatedContacts column.... an array of what?

Comment: The `relatedContacts` column is an array of pointers to `Contact` objects. For the query, `relatedContactObjects` is an array with only one object because `containsAllObjectsInArray` needs an NSArray. I really just want a count of the `Deal` objects where `relatedContacts` contains `self.contactObject`.

Comment: That makes your goal very easy to achieve.